# not getting data from shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have async task where i am getting data from server in JSONArray format. I want to save that data in shared preferences and display it in list view. i am using adapter.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    pojo = new Pojo();
    JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
    ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
    tii.add(tipoftheday);
    List<String> listTemp = tii;
    Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    for (int m=0; m<listTemp.size(); m++){
            temp.addAll(listTemp);
            editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday",temp);
            editor.commit();
    }
```

i am retrieving the value as in below code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("tipoftheday", null);
 for(String p : set)
 {
       pojo.setTip(p);
       tips.add(pojo);

 }
 tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(TipsActivity.this, tips);
 listTips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
```

but i am getting only one value. what is wrong in the code. can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, when you're storing the data, every time you're creating a new `ArrayList`.

Here:

```
ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And you're getting the prefs on every iteration of your outer `for` loop, you don't have to do this. Just get the reference outside your loop and use it when needed.

Here:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

---

Try to change your code to something like this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();


for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    pojo = new Pojo();
    JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");

    tii.add(tipoftheday);
}

List<String> listTemp = tii;
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);

temp.addAll(listTemp);
editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday",temp);
editor.commit();
```

---

**EDIT:** On your "retrieving" part of the code, you forgot to instantiate your `Pojo` object.

Like:

```
pojo = new Pojo();
```

So your last `for` loop should look something like:

```
for(String p : set) {
   pojo = new Pojo();
   pojo.setTip(p);
   tips.add(pojo);
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i got the mistake. but the problem is only one value is retrieved twice which is last added not two different values

Comment: still not working.. is there any mistake in retrieving the shared preferences

Comment: Will take a look. Wait.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are setting the Set value in preference every time i.e. in loop on each element that is why you can only get the last entered value. Change your following code

```
 Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    for (int m=0; m<listTemp.size(); m++){
            temp.addAll(listTemp);
            editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday",temp);
            editor.commit();
    }
```

Replace it with following

```
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    for (int m=0; m<listTemp.size(); m++){
            temp.addAll(listTemp);
    }
editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday",temp);
editor.commit();
```

And see if its working or not

**Edit:-**

Change your adding code to

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    pojo = new Pojo();
    JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
    tii.add(tipoftheday);

    }

List<String> listTemp = tii;
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
temp.addAll(listTemp);
editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday",temp);
editor.commit();
```

And retrieving code to

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("tipoftheday", null);
 for(String p : set)
 {
       pojo = new Pojo();
       pojo.setTip(p);
       tips.add(pojo);

 }
 tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(TipsActivity.this, tips);
 listTips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
```

See if its working or not

Comment: got the mistake but only one value is retrieved twice which is last added not two different values